# Epsilon-Delta proof when $f$is continous at $a$

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f$ is continous at $a$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ so that whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

I have no idea how to even begin this question and was wondering if anyone can give me hints on how to go upon proving this statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In plain English: by definition of continuous, you have that if $x$ or is close to $a$, then $f(x)$ is close to $f(a)$. So if two points $x$ and $y$ are close to $a$, then both $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are close to $f(a)$. Do you know something that can let you say that $f(x)$ is close to $f(y)$ as well?

> Triangle inequality! $$|p-q| = |p-r+r-q| \le |p-r| + |r-q|,$$ or in words: if both $p$ and $q$ are close to $r$, then the distance between $p$ and $q$ is no bigger than the sum of the distances $|p-r|$ and $|q-r|$ (draw a picture for help with the intuition).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For any real number $c$, $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |f(x)-c|+|f(y)-c|$$ by the Triangle Inequality.